# IIS 8 Duplicate Website

Tags: iis, iis-8

I'm coming from IIS 6 to a new server running IIS 8.

I have lots of websites which all run a shared virtual directory for their back end. When a new customer comes online I need to create a new website front end with all the associated settings, virtual folders etc.

In IIS 6 I just right click and exported an XML, then I could add a site from that XML..easy..just sets up an exact duplicate of the original site but that is not running (because the host headers are the same). Change those, update the name and I'm away.

In IIS 8 they seem to be making it much harder! I can deploy a site to an external XML file but this includes all the actual physical files etc not just the setup.

I tried to use appcmd which spits out a nice XML file with the configuration, but that wont import a duplicate so I have to edit it to change the site names and also the site ID which sort of defeats the object.

All I want to do is duplicate a site..whats up with making this so complicated, progress eh who wants it!

PS the appcmd route also doesnt backup anything from the web.config such as URL rewrite rules

Comment: go it iis.net and read the hosting guidelines. You seem to be woefully totally unaware of all the tools and best practices that are there.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already aware that IIS7/8 is very different and has a lot more tools available, especially for web farms and more complicated setups. In this case though it seems a very simple task has been lost. Unfortunately I dont have the time to learn an entire new methodology right now, though I am sure I will get into the scripting provision for manipulating sites especially, and was just looking for a quick way to duplicate a site in IIS8.